# c# string replace for keyword

Tags: c#, regex

I have a long string as below. I would like to replace some character when it found some keyword `(.abc_ or .ABC_)`. As the system read line by line, if the keyword is found, then it will replace the word infront to become `"john"`

```
insert into material.abc_Inventory; Delete * from table A; ....   
insert into job.ABC_Inventory; Show select .....; ....
```

Changed to

```
insert into john.ABC_Inventory; Delete * from table A;    
insert into john.ABC_Inventory; Show select .....;
```

Below is my code.

```
string output = string.Empty;
using (StringReader reader = new StringReader(content))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains(".ABC_"))
            line.Replace(" word in front of the keyword" + line.Substring(line.IndexOf(".ABC_")), " john" + line.Substring(line.IndexOf(".ABC_")));
            output += whole line of edited code; 

        else if (line.Contains(".abc_"))
            line.Replace(" word in front of the keyword" + line.Substring(line.IndexOf(".abc_")), " john" + line.Substring(line.IndexOf(".abc_")));
            output += whole line of edited code; 

        else
            output += line.ToString();
    }
}
```

I am not able to get the word material or job in front of the keyword.

Comment: Check Index of substring and Try to compare words in UPPER Case or Lower case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
content =  Regex.Replace(content, @"\s\w+\.(abc|ABC)_", " john.$1_");
```

Comment: can you make that into 1 line?

Comment: yes, don't know what I didn't think of it actually. I have edited accordingly.

Comment: +1. nice write-only solution :). Note: I suspect $1 should not be in replace string as it feels like .ABC_ should be removed from the output...

Answer (score 1):

Use String.Format instead of this:

```
var stringBuffer = new StringBuffer();
...
line = "insert into {0}.ABC_Inventory; Show select ..."
stringBuffer.AppendFormat(line, arg1, arg2, arg3);
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var list = line.Split(new[] {".abc_", ".ABC_"}, 
                              StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
if (list.Count() > 1)
{
    string toReplace = list.First().Split(' ').Last();
    string output = line.Replace(toReplace, "john");
}
```